# Insert Array into Table Oracle Apex

Tags: arrays, oracle, oracle-apex

I got an table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "USER"
  (     "NUMBER" VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "ROLE" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "QUESTION_ORDER" "T_NUMARRAY",
        "FORENAME" VARCHAR2(20),
        "SURNAME" VARCHAR2(20),
        CONSTRAINT "USER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("NUMBER")
  USING INDEX ENABLE
  )
VARRAY "QUESTION_ORDER" STORE AS SECUREFILE LOB
/
```

I'm trying to Update the column Order with an Array which is filled with numbers.
My Code which generates the Array:

```
DECLARE
     TYPE T_NUMARRAY IS TABLE OF number INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
     numArray T_NUMARRAY;
BEGIN
     SELECT PAGE_ID BULK COLLECT INTO numArray FROM APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES WHERE APPLICATION_ID = 943 AND PAGE_NAME LIKE '%Questions_%' ORDER BY PAGE_ID ASC;
     FOR i IN 1 .. numArray.Count Loop
        UPDATE USER SET Question_Order = numArray WHERE QNUMMER = :APP_USER;
     END LOOP;
END
```

When I try to Update the entrys in the table then I get the error: 
ORA-06550: line 9, colum 48: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
I don't know how to INSERT the array correctly. Maybe someone can help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a table with a column of type `T_NUMARRAY`, then `T_NUMARRAY` has to be defined at the schema level using the `CREATE TYPE` statement. If that is true, then you must not define `T_NUMARRAY` locally. Remove the line right after `DECLARE` where you define a local collection with the same name.

I would feel much better about this answer if you provided more information in your question. Please add the DDL that creates the table for starters.

Do you really, really need to **store** the data as an array? I would avoid that if possible and instead store the data in the "normal" way.